# Operator Error in Visual Studio (error C2784)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having a problem with some of my operators. The operators in my search and deleteWord. In search I'm trying to check that a word in my list matches a search word. In deleteWord I'm trying to check that the word I want to delete matches perfectly with a word in my list and then delete it.

I've looked up how to fix my operator but I don't understand. Thank you in advance.

**Some errors:**

Error 1     error C2784: 'bool std::opeator >=(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const_Elem*): could not deduce template argument for 'const_Elem*' for 'const LinkedList'

Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator >=(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'std::string'

Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator >=(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const LinkedList'

Error   29  error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Error   59  IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Definition of the node
struct linkedList{ //linked list
    string word;  //node holds string word
    linkedList *next; //points to next node
    linkedList *prev; //points to prev node
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        LinkedList(); //default const
        ~LinkedList(); //destructor
        const LinkedList& operator = (const LinkedList &); //overload the assignment operator
        void initializeList(); //func to init list to an empty state
        void read();
        void printForward(linkedList *firstWord);
        void printBackward(linkedList *lastWord);
        void insert();
        bool search(const LinkedList& searchItem) const; 
        void deleteWord(const LinkedList& deleteItem); 
        void clear();
    protected:
        int count;
        linkedList *firstWord; //pointer to the first node
        linkedList *lastWord; //pointer to the last node
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    firstWord = NULL;
    lastWord = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
...
... //more code
...
bool LinkedList::search(const LinkedList& searchItem) const
{
    bool found = false;

    linkedList *temp; //pointer to traverse list
    temp = firstWord;

    while (temp != NULL && !found)
        if (temp->word >= searchItem)
            found = true;
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    if (found)
        found = (temp->word == searchItem); //test for equality
    return found;   
}

void LinkedList::deleteWord(const LinkedList& deleteItem) 
{
    linkedList *temp; //pointer to traverse the list
    linkedList *trailTemp; ///pointer just before temp
    bool found;

    if (firstWord == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
    else if (firstWord->word == deleteWord){ //node to be deleted is the firstWord
        temp = firstWord;
        firstWord = firstWord->next;

        if (firstWord != NULL)
            firstWord->prev = NULL;

        else
            lastWord = NULL;

        count--;
        delete temp;
    }
    else{
        found = false;
        temp = firstWord;

        while (temp !=NULL && !found) //search the list
            if (temp->word >= deleteWord)
                found = true;
            else
                temp = temp->next;

        if (temp == NULL)
            cout << "The word to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
        else if (temp->word == deleteWord){ //check for equality
            trailTemp = temp->prev;
            trailTemp->next = temp->next;

            if (temp->next != NULL)
                temp->next->prev = trailTemp;

            if (temp == lastWord)
                lastWord = trailTemp;

            count--;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
            cout << "The word to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
    }
}
...
... //more code 
...
#endif
```

Comment: What is the exact error or errors you are receiving?

Comment: are you sure you need to return `const LinkedList&` as the return of `operator=`? Why the `const`? And you are missing the `#endif` at the end.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added some errors I have.

Comment: Also, show the definition of `operator=` in the code.

Comment: @vsoftco No I'm not sure I need that, I'm a beginner. I'm not missing #endif. I didn't want to put in all my code, I've edited my post to show that it's at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (temp->word >= searchItem)
```

is comparing a `std::string` with a `LinkedList`. You want to compare the `word` in `temp` with a string.

Change the function to:

```
bool LinkedList::search(const std::string& searchItem) const
```

Most of your other errors are variations on this theme.

Edit: mistook `LinkedList` for `linkedList` - please don't have a struct and class with the same name but different cases. It is very confusing.

Comment: The change in function worked. Thank you. I promise never to have my struct and class named the same with different cases (^.^)

Comment: get rid of `const` in the return type of `operator=`, `a=b=c` will work, but think about what happens if you do `(a=b)=c`.